# How to convert Pandas rows into dictionaries a certain way

Tags: python, json, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame (`df`) like this:

```
   FileID  MatchCat  Match  Freq  CatIDType  CatID
0  001     fruit     apple  3     food       123
1  001     company   apple  3     tech       456
```

I have used the following to convert this to be able to write it to json (not done here):

```py
    temp_df = (df.groupby(['FileID','Match','Freq'], as_index = False)
        .apply(lambda x: x[['MatchCat','CatIDType','CatID']].to_dict('r'))
        .reset_index())
    temp_df.columns = ['FileID','Match','Freq', 'MatchInfo']
    j = temp_df.to_dict('records')
```

Ouptut of `j`:

```py
   [
    {
      'FileID': '001',
      'Match': 'AAPL',
      'Freq': 3,
      'MatchInfo': [
                     {
                       'CatIdType': 'food', 
                       'CatId': '123', 
                       'MatchCat': 'fruit'
                     }
                   ]
    },
    {
      'FileID': '001',
      'Match': 'AAPL',
      'Freq': 3,
      'MatchInfo': [
                     {
                       'CatIdType': 'tech', 
                       'CatId': '456', 
                       'MatchCat': 'company'
                     }
                   ]
    }
   ]
```

However, I want to now look like this (consolidate into one since `Match` and `FileID` is same for both):

```py
    [
     {
      'FileID': '001',
      'Match': 'AAPL',
      'Freq': 3,
      'MatchInfo': [
                     {
                       'CatIdType': 'food', 
                       'CatId': '123', 
                       'MatchCat': 'fruit'
                     }, 
                     {
                       'CatIdType': 'tech', 
                       'CatId': '456', 
                       'MatchCat': 'company'
                     }
                   ]
    }
   ]
```

Is there a simple way to change the code to achieve this?

Comment: That is not particularly solid dictionary code. If you have multiple sub-dictionaries with the same keys, then they each need to have a key to associate with each sub-dictionary treating them as values.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that in general it is completely fine to use lists within dictionaries (as it is in JSON) however, if the objects in the list are dictionaries with duplicate keys, it has always been my experience that you do not tacitly allow the list index to serve as the new key, you include a unique ID for each sub-dictionary  `[ {id1:Dictionary1}, {id2:Dictionary2}]`

Comment: it is not a hard rule, but typically you would provide a unique identifier so that if you unpacked the list they would not conflict with each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(
    df.groupby(['FileID', 'Match', 'Freq'])['MatchCat', 'CatIDType', 'CatID']
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='r'))
        .reset_index(name='MatchInfo').to_dict(orient='r')
)
```

---

```
[{'FileID': 1,
  'Freq': 3,
  'Match': 'apple',
  'MatchInfo': [{'CatID': 123, 'CatIDType': 'food', 'MatchCat': 'fruit'},
                {'CatID': 456, 'CatIDType': 'tech', 'MatchCat': 'company'}]}]
```